# Tool for Generating Graph from Xml data

Tags: java, xml, diagram

I want to generate graph from large xml files. It is actually a calling context tree generated by an execution of the program. A small file looks like below:

[image]

From this xml I would like to have a graph which Contains 4 nodes(one node for each method tag) i.e. main, methodA, methodB and method C. As the tree shows (from the indentation) main() calls methodA, then methodA calls methodB and methodC. So the I want a graph'/figure like something like below:

[image]

**Are there any open source tools which can do this for me ? The xml files are extremely large (around 7 MB) so the graph would really be huge. I want the tool to handle this properly. It is good if the tool works on linux otherwise on windows will also be ok. But first preference is linux.**

I can also consider some good library in java through which I can do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My suggestion would be [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/yed) - it is not open source, but free and cross-platform (Java-based and works amazingly smooth on Linux with Oracle's JDK) and uses open standards for input/output. It is capable of visually arranging networks with thousands of nodes and has an import tool that can read xml files. 
Since there is no single best way to import an xml file into a graph structure, you can associate an XSLT file and convert the input to [GraphML](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org) - yEd can automatically apply the XSLT file to your xml file and then calculate a nice drawing that can then be analyzed or exported.

[Here](http://docs.yworks.com/yfiles/doc/developers-guide/graphml.html#graphml_xslt) are links to some XSL example stylesheets that you can use as a basis.

Comment: Thanks for your response Sebastian. I downloaded yED 3.9.2. From what u said, it seems that I just need to import xml file into yED and it will conver it to GraphML and then will generate graph. But I could not find an option to import xml file into yED ? Could you please tell me how do I do that ?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I am kind of not understanding what you are saying by "yEd can automatically apply the XSLT file to your xml file and then calculate a nice drawing that can then be analyzed or exported." Do you mean First I should convert my xml file to GraphMl and then should open that graphml file into yED ? I tried to open sample graphml file to yED but it does not display a proper graph ? Could you please explain me what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Well, yED just accepts xml format. we just have to select File-Open and choose xml+xss in file type. Graph should be displayed properly. I dont know why Sebastian told to convert it to GraphML n all.Thanks to Sebastian for suggesting good tool.

Comment: If you write your own XSL file (you will probably have to unless your XML is trivial) - the XSL needs to output GraphML xml. You will not see this GraphML intermediate result, however yED will actually parse GraphML in the end. XML + XSL = GraphML -> yED

Comment: When I tried to open xml file of 1 MB, it shows me error like "yEd has encountered the following error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" after displaying graph from the file. The shown graph is incomplete. So do you know how to handle large files with this and what does this error actually means in yED ? Thanks

Comment: @user523956: I have not seen this error before. You should contact the support team - they will definitely help you in the case of an exception here: [yEd Support](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_helpresources.html)